# Opening VS Code live-server in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use live-server in VS Code and want it to open in Chrome. However, despite having changed the settings in VS Code and restarted it, it still opens live-server in Firefox.
Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.
I've included my live-server VS Code settings.

```
{
  "liveServer.settings.port": 5500,
  "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "chrome --incognito --remote-debugging-port=9222",
  "liveServer.settings.NoBrowser": false,
  "liveServer.settings.ingnoreFiles": [
    ".vscode/**",
    "**/*.scss",
    "**/*.sass",
    "**/*.ts"
   [
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you have probably resolved this issue by now. But I am using Arch Linux and had to point to the directory and give the proper name for chrome on Linux. You're also missing the closing bracket for your json data.

```
{
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "/usr/bin/google-chrome 
 stable"
 }
```